# Can't get expect_table_columns_to_match_set to work

Tags: python, pandas, great-expectations

If I define `df_asset` as follows

```
import great_expectations as ge
df_asset = ge.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], 'B': [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]}))
```

then the expect_table_columns_to_match_ordered_list method works (output on 2nd line):

```
df_asset.expect_table_columns_to_match_ordered_list(['A', 'B'])
```

```
{'success': True, 'result': {'observed_value': ['A', 'B']}}
```

However the following does not:

```
df_asset.expect_table_columns_to_match_set(set(['A', 'B']))
```

```
AttributeError: 'PandasDataset' object has no attribute 'expect_table_columns_to_match_set'
```

The Great Expectations version is 0.7.6. What is going wrong here?

Comment: what I can see from your error is that the method doesn't exist in the version that you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to increase your version. I tried your code on my google colab and was able to run successfully(ge version 0.15.43)

```
pip install great_expectations  # version is 0.15.43

import great_expectations as ge
import pandas as pd
df_asset = ge.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], 'B': [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]}))
df_asset.expect_table_columns_to_match_set(set(['A', 'B']))

#{
  "exception_info": {
    "raised_exception": false,
    "exception_traceback": null,
    "exception_message": null
  },
  "meta": {},
  "result": {
    "observed_value": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ]
  },
  "success": true,
  "expectation_config": {
    "meta": {},
    "expectation_type": "expect_table_columns_to_match_set",
    "kwargs": {
      "column_set": [
        "B",
        "A"
      ],
      "result_format": "BASIC"
    }
  }
}
```